# How to process a random value to get an xy coordinate?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

So I'm trying to use PIL to plot some RGB values to create an image.

The code I'm using for the plotting is as follows:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

class DrawDisplay(object):
    def __init__(self, size_x, size_y):
        self.size_x = size_x                                       #Length of the image
        self.size_y = size_y                                       #Width of the image
        self.img = Image.new("RGB", (self.size_x, self.size_y))    #Creates the drawing canvas
    def plot(self, xy, colour):
        d = ImageDraw.Draw(self.img)
        d.point(xy, colour)                                        #xy is co-ordinate in form of tuple, colour is rgb value in form of tuple
    def write(self, filename):
        self.img.save(filename)                                    #Saves image with the variable filename as the name
```

I know that there are no problems with the code above because I have tested it with:

```
dd = DrawDisplay(64, 64)                                           #Utilises the drawing class
for i in range(64):
    for j in range(64):
        r = i * 4    #Pretty colours
        g = j * 4
        b = 0
        dd.plot((i, j),(r, g, b))                                  #Uses method from earlier with i and j as x and y
dd.write("testname.png")                                           #Saves the image as testname
```

And I get a nice pretty image if I click on testname.png in my folder

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aezJ0.jpg)

Now say I had an unordered array with every number up until 64^2 or 4096:

```
my_list = shuffle(range(4096))
```

Now this is where I need help, how could I process every value in `my_list` to get an xy co-ordinate tuple using a formula/function?

Here is another way to view this question:

Imagine a 4x4 grid. If I put 1 in to this function my output would be (1,1) (or (0,0) if you want to make this problem simpler.)

```
  1 2 3 4    #Visualised
1 1 - - -
2 - - - -
3 - - - -
4 - - - -
```

16 as an input would output (4,4) (or (3,3)):

```
  1 2 3 4
1 - - - -
2 - - - -
3 - - - -
4 - - - 16
```

And 7 outputs (3,2) (or (2,1)):

```
  1 2 3 4
1 - - - -
2 - - 7 -
3 - - - -
4 - - - -
```

What would my formula/function be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have various grid sizes then this can help. It's not most elegant, but it works

```
def fun(val, grid):
    pos = []
    for val in lst:
        x = val//grid[1]
        r = val%grid[1]
        if(r==0):
            pos.append([x, grid[1]])
        else:
            pos.append([x+1, val-(x*grid[1]])
   return pos
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
def idx2point(idx):
   return (idx/64,idx%64)
```

You can add 1 to each coordinate if you want to count from 1 rather than 0.

Comment: Yes this works perfectly however I have just one question. What should I do if I let the user choose the width but still have a fixed amount of values (i.e. turn 64 into variables width and f(w))? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I have another function for computing the coordinates:

```
from math import floor, sqrt

def f(num):
    a = floor(sqrt(num))
    if a**2 == num:
        return (a, a)
    b = (num - a**2 + 1) // 2
    if num % 2 == a % 2:
        return (b, a+1)
    else:
        return (a+1, b)
```

This gives the following results:

```
f(1)
>>> (1, 1)
f(9)
>>> (3, 3)
f(10)
>>> (4, 1)
f(11)
>>> (1, 4)
f(12)
>>> (4, 2)
```